# Make draggable sortable with the droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I made a drag & drop system. The draggable items can be dropped in placeholders. Those placeholders are added dynamically based on the amount of draggable items.

But when I drag a draggable item between those placeholders, it doesn't get appended to it. I've tried many many things but I'm still stuck on it.

I'm afraid that I'll need to change a lot of the code, but maybe one of you has a genius idea on how to solve this.

[**Here's the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/opmd46t2/6/)

Is it possible to check wether it has been placed on a placeholder, or not?

This is my droppable function:

```
function dropping () {
    $("li.placeholder").droppable({
        accept: ".to-drag",
        hoverClass: correct_placeholder,
        activeClass: active_placeholder,
        revert: false,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var dragging = ui.draggable.clone().find("img").remove();
            $(this).append(dragging).addClass("dropped");
            $(this).droppable('disable');

            var day = $(ui.draggable).attr('data-id');
            var index = $(event.target).index();

            $(this).attr("data-id", day);
            $(this).attr("date-order", index);
            $(this).addClass("drop-"+ index);
            $(this).attr("data-content", "");

            $(this).find("h1, p").remove();

            var dropped = $(".dropped").length;
            var original = $(".placeholder").length;

            if (dropped === original) {
                $("li.placeholder").removeClass(blank_placeholder);
                $("#dropzone").append('<li class="placeholder ' + blank_placeholder +' " data-id="" data-order=""></li>');
                init();
            }

            $(".remove").click(function() {
                var removable = $(this).parent();
                var modal = $(this).attr("data-modal");
                $(".modal-"+modal).remove();
                if (dropped > original) {
                    $(this).parent().droppable('enable')

                    removable.remove();
                    removable.removeClass("dropped");
                    removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().droppable('enable');

                    removable.empty();
                    removable.removeClass("dropped");
                    removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");
                }
                init();
            });
        }
    });

    $("li.dropped").droppable({
        disabled: function (event, ui) {
            disabled: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you considered just using the sortable function and connecting the two lists? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists - I don't think you'd need half as much code...

Comment: The thing is I need those placeholders. They can't be removed...

Comment: As in, all 5 need to be visible permanently? Because sortable does have a [placeholder](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/sortable/#option-placeholder)

Comment: Yup, but I'm using that class.. (see jsfiddle)

Comment: I will try this out tho, I've interpreted this wrong..